# Why we can't follow other users on stackoverflow?

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes I am eager to see the activity of other users, who I am interested in . Is there any good way, except to search the id each time, to achieve this?
Why can't stackoverflow have the follow feature?

Comment: Bookmark activity page of the user....

Comment: Because this is not a social network.

Comment: @Ral Zarek, I want to know more about why we can't not only how.

Comment: @gunr2171 we can follow on "quora", however I don't know whether we should define quora as social network.

Comment: @notbad, we are not quora. We are Stack Overflow. Not all sites have to be the same, like _not having to login to view the content on the site_.

Comment: The "why" is mainly that this site wants to focus on the content, not on the users. It's a cultural thing.

Answer (score 9):

There is an RSS feed on each user page (user feed link at the bottom of the page, to the right) - you can use that to see what they are doing on the site, to a limited extent.

> Why can't stackoverflow have the follow feature?

Because Stack Overflow is a Question and answer site. It is not about the users - it is about the content.

In other words - Stack Overflow is not a social networking site and will never become one.

Comment: Some times you feel like you want to give a gift to the one who answered your question , lets think about this! and step to make a social side of this awesome community